# How to refresh or update all fragment from the viewpager android

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have viewpager with tablayout, and have 3 fragment in it. In my fragment 2 and 3 , I have swipe to refresh to update data from firebase database.

I want it refresh with 1 button in toolbar, and refresh all of the fragment inside it.

1 more problem is, i have to swipe refresh 2 times the fragment to update the recyclerview.....
I dont know how to do it, please help

**TwoFragment**

```
public static final String TAG = "TWO_FRAGMENT";

@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {

        } else {
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_course");
            users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            daftarTugasRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tugas");
            mTugasRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tugas_course");
            mFlagTugas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("flag_tugas");

            LoadData();
        }
    }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override public void run() {
                        LoadData();
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        listTugas.clear();

                    }
                    private void onLoaded() {
                        swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }, 500);
            }
        });
```

**MainActivity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
reloadFragment("TWO_FRAGMENT");

        setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }



        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }




    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

//        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

protected void reloadFragment(String TAG){
        // Reload current fragment
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        FragmentTransaction ft =this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779769/5575410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), put this in all your fragments:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(ViewEvent viewEvent) {
        if (viewEvent.getMessage().equals("updateViews")) {
            updateView();

        }


    }
```

and when you want to update you can send an event like this:

```
 EventBus.getDefault().post(new ViewEvent("updateViews"));
```

**PS**: ViewEvent is an object that you must create with what to send to all suscribed fragments.

```
public class ViewEvent {

    private String message;

    public ViewEvent( String message) {

        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I add in MainActivity? and how to subsribe fragmentsqwer?

Comment: The frist code lets you suscribe to any ViewEvent sended , so your fragments must suscribe first and when your data is update either in MainAct or fragments you send an event like second code.

Comment: cannot find symbol getMessage

Comment: Im really sorry, can you provide me with my code sir?

Comment: so I want refresh all fragment in viewpager, I called  EventBus.getDefault().post(new ViewEvent("updateViews"));
in main activity?

Comment: Where you want YES!

Comment: This is really great, It works too. But the problem is, I have to click 2 times to update the view, can u help me?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/epG35Qij , this code is really complex i think. But the main function is to populate recyclerview and check the new data or not. the last valueventlistener is to check the newdata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182772/discussion-between-yehezkiel-yehezkiel-and-addell-el-haddad).

Answer (score 0):

Just call the following method on your button click to refresh the Fragments -

```
 protected void reloadFragment(String TAG){
        // Reload current fragment
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Declare your TAG variable inside the Fragment by the following line of code -

```
public static final String TAG = "HOME_FRAGMENT";
```

and whenever you are pushing the Fragment in your activity kindly use the same TAG like this -

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).replace(container, fragment, tag).commit();
```

You just need to have a TAG for each of your Fragment. Hope you will get the solution using this.

Comment: how to add the tag to the fragment? im using viewpager tab layout to create fragment

Comment: I think better to make a public method in the fragment and call it from the activity instead of detaching and attaching the fragment.

Comment: Should I add android:tag="fragmenttwo"
to my parent view fragment?

Comment: @AyushKhare I did it, and it works. But the problem is, when i close and open app, its not update. I have to close open 2 times, or swipe refresh 2 times.

Comment: @yehezkielyehezkiel you don't have to use a xml property here, just create your fragment using the above code snippet so that TAG will come into picture and it will help then to refresh your Fragment. Kindly see the updated code for the reference. Thanks.

Comment: @AyushKhare check my updated code sir, sorry for missunderstand. it showing me error now

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference